# Why NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, exception, routes

I want to submit some form information into my table, but this error is showing, if i do `Route::resource('userinfo','infoController@index');` the error gone, but i can't insert data, what will be the solution.

## My controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\infomodel;

class infoController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
 {
   $alldata = infomodel::all();
   return $alldata;
 }

 public function create()
 {
    return view('userinfo.create');
 }

 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $input = $request->all();
    infomodel:: create($input);
    return redirect('infomodel');
 }
}
```

## My model

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class infomodel extends Model
{
    Protected $table = "info";
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'age', 'hometown'];
}
```

## My route web.php

```
<?php
Route::resource('userinfo','infoController');

Route::get('/solid', function () {
    return view('solid.index');
});
```

## This is view create.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Userinfo</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="width:350px; margin:0 auto;
margin-top:25px;">

{!! Form::open(['route' => 'userinfo.store']) !!}


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Enter Your name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name= "email" placeholder="Enter email">

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="Enter age">

  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Hometown</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hometown" placeholder="Enter hometown">

  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

  </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you also show your form (or at least part where there are `<form>` tags)?

Comment: i am giving the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `store` method

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    infomodel:: create($input);
    return redirect('infomodel');
}
```

You redirect user to non-existing route `infomodel`.

Try this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    infomodel:: create($input);

    // You can try 'return back()' as well
    return redirect()->route('userinfo.index');
}
```